# Create a log of opened reports

Tags: ms-access-2010

I would like to create a log of all of the times a report is run in my access application.  Short of putting a line of code in the open of each report or creating a custom sub to open reports, is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need some code in each of your open events, but it shouldn't be that tricky.

If it were me, I'd set up a table to store all the audit records of when a report is run.. something with these fields perhaps:

[image]

I'd then create a new module to write a subroutine by going to Create > Module:

[image]

I'd then write a public subroutine that I can call from any of the events that runs a report. The subroutine would also have an argument (rptName) so I can pass the name of the report that is running the subroutine to the subroutine so that the subroutine can use it to populate the "ReportName" field of my table:

```vb
Public Sub ReportLog(rptName As String)

    Dim Db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set Db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("OpenedReportLogs")

    rs.AddNew
    rs!ReportName = rptName
    rs!RunDate = Now()
    rs!RunBy = Environ("USERNAME")
    rs.Update

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set Db = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above code opens the "OpenedReportLogs" table I created, adds a new record, and populates the fields of that new record with the necessary data.

To run this code when a given report is run, I simply call it from the event that runs a given report. So if, for example, I had a dashboard with 3 buttons that each run a different report, like so:

[image]

I'd go into the on-click event of each button and call the name of my subroutine; I'd be sure to provide the "rptName" argument as well, which in this case will be the name of the report that is running the subroutine:

[image]

Clicking each button puts the following entries into my "OpenedReportLogs" table:

[image]